# Is it possible to validate when an entered password is wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, try-catch, webdriverwait

When writing an auto-it for safari with selenium, is it possible to know if a password inserted into a website login is wrong?

I've tried using `try:` and `except:`, but selenium doesn't raise an error when the password is wrong.

an example would be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver=webdriver.Safari()
driver.get(r'website')
usr=driver.find_element_by_name(r'username')
usr.clear()
usr.send_keys(r'username')
pas=driver.find_element_by_name(r'password')
pas.clear()
pas.send_keys(r'password')
pas.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Which website are you trying???

Comment: If you can't shere the website shere the HTML! (include the error of the wrong password)

Comment: https://auth.florimont.ch/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fflore.florimont.ch%2Fhome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable` and following css selector.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(r'https://auth.florimont.ch/cas/login;jsessionid=8B5A3B65779756F3CF71ACB41E578AC3?service=https%3A%2F%2Fflore.florimont.ch%2Fhome')
usr=driver.find_element_by_name(r'username')
usr.clear()
usr.send_keys(r'username')
pas=driver.find_element_by_name(r'password')
pas.clear()
pas.send_keys(r'password')
pas.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#fm1 #msg"))).text)
```

**Print on console:**

```
Invalid credentials.
```

**Browser snapshot:**

[image]

Comment: when i try this i get an error saying  that webdriverwait is not defined

Comment: try now.Sorry I have forgot to update imports initially.Copy entire code now.

Answer (score 0):

To validate if a username/password inserted into a website login is wrong you can use a `try/catch{}` block and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://auth.florimont.ch/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fflore.florimont.ch%2Fhome")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#username"))).send_keys("a_random_programmer")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#password").send_keys("a_random_programmer")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.btn-submit").click()
  try:
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "//h2[text()='Enter your Username and Password']//preceding::div[1]"), "Invalid credentials."))
      print("Invalid Login")
  except TimeoutException as e:
      print("Valid Login")
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Invalid Login
  ```